Best translation for "zumutbar"
I'm trying to find a good English translation for Ingeborg Bachmann's saying "Die Wahrheit ist dem Menschen zumutbar". Automatic translations translate that to something like "The truth is reasonable for man" but I don't think that "reasonable" hits the mark. Any suggestions?

I am not sure this is on-topic here. If you asked the meaning of zumutbar, it would be about German. Finding a translation into English isn't about German.

Well, if you don't understand a word in it's details you can't translate it. Therefore you could reinterprete the question and just explain the general meaning of zumutbar and then have the asker figure out the meaning in other languages.

@JonathanHerrera Fair enough. But asking for the meaning of zumutbar would be dishonest since I definitely know the meaning as a native German speaker, I just didn't know how to express the same in English. Anyway, I'm happy with the one answer I got.

@ErichKitzmüller If you want to know how to express it in English, english.stackexchance.com is the place to go.

How about: "The human being can be burdened with the truth"
A Zumutung is usually an imposition of a mostly negative duty or experience. So "Es ist eine Zumutung" is a common complaint about a situation. So the sentence both acknowledges that it's a burden and a negative imposition to someone else, but also argues that it's something that is bearable and therefore acceptable to be burdened with.

I like this translation very much, thank you.
